# Is there a way to add infinite number of Add More on webforms in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, webforms

Simple question for all of you here dealing with Drupal 6.x...

With Drupal's Add More module, is there a way to configure my webform so that there is no limit on how many of a specific fields I can add more of?

For instance, I have a web form where users can request titles. I would like to enable the user to add as many titles as they would like. Is this doable or does there have to be a theoretical limit?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no. At least I've never found a way to do it. I've always had to add 10+ fields and use [webform_conditional](https://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) to hide them until they fill in one and then show the next, or provide a drop down so they can select how many fields to fill. Not ideal but I'm not sure any other way to do it.